# mod_rewrite appends query string when not using trailing slash

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've spent some time on Google and SO trying to figure this out and I have now had to resort to asking yet another mod_rewrite question....

I am using mod_rewrite and for the most part it works fine.

The part I am having problems with is:

```
# Load pages for health-it while keeping the URL masked
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^health-it/([-a-z0-9]+)/? /health-it/loadPage.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have a URI that I want:

```
/health-it/aimsconsultant
```

The problem is, mod_rewrite is doing this:

```
/health-it/aimsconsultant/?p=aimsconsultant
```

The page still loads but the URI is the issue.

```
/health-it/aimsconsultant/
```

Works as expected. It should be noted that /health-it/aimsconsultant is a directory and maybe this is the cause? I believe that Apache redirects to append the trailing slash for directories but why is it appending the query string?

It works perfect for internal pages (no directory for internal pages):

```
/health-it/aimsconsultant/manufacturer-signup
```

and

```
/health-it/aimsconsultant/manufacturer-signup/
```

work properly.

The only issue is on the first level... This makes no sense to me and I am baffled as to why this is happening. Please, can someone enlighten me on how to fix this and why this is working in this manner?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, sorry, I misread the ? for a $ !

Tried adding this, it seems to to the job:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

By default, it's On, and that's why when Apache tries to get the canonical representation of your URL, it falls back onto the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific entry for the URL version without trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^health-it/([-a-z0-9]+)? /health-it/loadPage.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

I've already had this kind of problem, where mod_rewrite ends with appending the query string, even without QSA flag. Don't know the reason why...

Comment: I tried that already and again just to be sure. /? should suffice since it leaves the slash as optional. Thanks for the suggestion though but it still didn't work