# Phantom directories confusing mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To begin with, I had the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704592/mod-rewrite-appends-query-string-when-not-using-trailing-slash) (Cliff's notes: mod_rewrite appends a query string if requested URI is a real directory).

The solution accepted there (add "DirectorySlash Off" to .htaccess) didn't work for me. This isn't what I'm hung up on, and I bring it up only in case it indicates anything germane.

After some thought, I decided it probably wasn't great to have navigable rewritten links that "look like" references to real directories anyway, so I decided to rename the relevant directories. Now mod_rewrite still treats requests for things that *used to be* directory names as if they still were.

So, in summary:

- [domain]/foo used to exist but doesn't anymore
- mod_rewrite rewrites requests for "[domain]/foo" as "[domain]/foo/?p=foo"
- [domain]/bar never existed
- requests for '[domain]/bar' are handled as expected

The relevant directory's .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitedir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Experimentation with commenting/uncommenting the condition excluding directories from the rewriterule has produced no change.

It feels like it's referencing a cached directory structure, but Googling assures me Apache has no cache. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache? It's going to remember the `/foo` -> `/foo/` redirect

Comment: Well, my face is red. That did it. Browsers! /fistshake